# Create time intervals based on values in one column / SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, gaps-and-islands

I need to create query that will return time intervals from table, that has attributes for (almost) every day.
The original table looks like the following:

```
Person | Date       | Date_Type
-------|------------|----------
Sam    | 01.06.2020 |  Vacation
Sam    | 02.06.2020 |  Vacation
Sam    | 03.06.2020 |  Work
Sam    | 04.06.2020 |  Work
Sam    | 05.06.2020 |  Work
Frodo  | 01.06.2020 |  Work
Frodo  | 02.06.2020 |  Work
.....
```

And the desired should look like:

```
Person | Date_Interval         | Date_Type
-------|-----------------------|----------
Sam    | 01.06.2020-02.06.2020 |  Vacation
Sam    | 03.06.2020-05.06.2020 |  Work
Frodo  | 01.06.2020-02.06.2020 |  Work
.....
```

Will be grateful for any idea :)

Comment: So, if a date is missing, how should that be handled? Should the Date_Type be assumed to be the same as the then-most-recent Date_Type for that Person? Should the intervals with missing data be treated as a "separate date type" and shown as such in the output? Or should they just be ignored - just show intervals of CONSECUTIVE dates with the same Date_Type?

Comment: Also: What is your Oracle version? Until version 11.2, the "tabibitosan method" (illustrated in Gordon Linoff's and GMB's answers) was the most efficient, but since version 12.1 such problems can be solved more efficiently with `match_recognize`.

Comment: 1st - answer you under GMB comments
2nd - I have 12c, but may be i'll have to rewrite it in Postgre soon, so.. )

Comment: OK, so if you must re-write under another DB version of SQL, you are better off without `match_recognize`; if the assumptions in GMB's answer are OK for you, then that is indeed the best answer. (Difference of two ROW_NUMBER calls, to get "consecutive row" intervals even if the dates are not consecutive.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reads like a gaps-and-island problem. Here is one approach:

```
select person, min(date) startdate, max(date) enddate, date_type
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by person order by date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by person, date_type order by date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by person, date_type, rn1 - rn2
```

This also works if not all dates are contiguous (since you stated that you have *almost* all dates, I understood you don't have them all).

Comment: Seems to work perfectly, thanks! And now i also know of this general kind of problems :) BTW, did i get it right, that in `(rn1-rn2)` we will get different results for every period, and it doesn't matter how many of them are there for one person?

Comment: I don't follow. If a "missing date" is sandwiched between two dates with data, with the same Date_Type, then the missing date will be INCLUDED in the intervals shown in the output. If the dates with data on the two sides of a missing date have DIFFERENT Date_Type, then the "missing date" will NOT be included in the intervals in the output. That seems so inconsistent that I have a hard time thinking of a business use case where this would be the desired handling.

Comment: Oh.You are right. I guess it will be OK for my task to have these assumptions made. Actually there shouldn't be many lags like these (only depends on the HR data correctness), and if any are found - i'll tell them :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.

To get adjacent days with the same `date_type`, you can subtract a sequence.  It will be constant for adjacent days.  Then you can aggregate:

```
select person, date_type, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, date_type
                                             order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by person, date_type, (date - seqnum);
```

Comment: Do you have any questions for the OP, regarding missing dates? He mentioned them, but he didn't tell us how they must be handled, and the sample data doesn't have any examples. In your answer you assume they must be handled in a specific way, which may or may not be what the OP needs; regardless, it would be very helpful if you would state your assumption explicitly.

Comment: Tried this one, it seems not to work if we have several different periods for one person, for example: type1, then type2 and then type1 again. This solution will make a single interval for all type1 dates. The version of @GMB with two row_nums works better in this case.

Comment: @DenisKa - Gordon't solution is simpler than GMB's (but it makes a different assumption about missing dates!) - except that Gordon sometimes doesn't pay attention to details. To correct this answer, add Date_Type to the PARTITION BY clause of the ROW_NUMBER function.

Comment: Yeah. I've tried it too after commenting :) Also works well with correct partition. 
Thanks a lot for your analysis!

Comment: @DenisKa . . . I suspect that this version is close to what you actually want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest methods is to use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform a row-by-row comparison and aggregation:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY Person
  ORDER     BY "DATE"
  MEASURES
    FIRST( "DATE" )    AS start_date,
    LAST( "DATE")      AS end_date,
    FIRST( Date_Type ) AS date_type
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( successive_dates+ )
  DEFINE
    SUCCESSIVE_DATES AS (
          FIRST( Date_Type ) = NEXT( Date_Type )
      AND MAX( "DATE" ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY = NEXT( "DATE")
    )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Person, "DATE", Date_Type ) AS
SELECT 'Sam',   DATE '2020-06-01', 'Vacation' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sam',   DATE '2020-06-02', 'Vacation' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sam',   DATE '2020-06-03', 'Work' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sam',   DATE '2020-06-04', 'Work' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sam',   DATE '2020-06-05', 'Work' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Frodo', DATE '2020-06-01', 'Work' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Frodo', DATE '2020-06-02', 'Work' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> PERSON | START_DATE          | END_DATE            | DATE_TYPE
> :----- | :------------------ | :------------------ | :--------
> Frodo  | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | Work     
> Sam    | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | 2020-06-01 00:00:00 | Vacation 
> Sam    | 2020-06-03 00:00:00 | 2020-06-04 00:00:00 | Work
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dcc0e560ccbe5c0d66c4a9f3f3b1ae7f)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try it too to compare, but won't use))  because it seems that we'll switch to another DB soon...